# Each thread should run for particular duration of time

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I am working on a project in which I will be spawning multiple threads from a multithreaded code.

Suppose I am spawning 10 threads, then I need to make sure each thread should be running for particular duration of time.

For example, if I want `each thread` should run for `30 minutes`, then in the `config.properties` file, I will be having `TOTAL_RUNNING_TIME=30`

So I came up with the below design to make sure each thread is running for `30 minutes`.

```
private static long durationOfRun;
private static long sleepTime;

 public static void main(String[] args) {

      // create thread pool with given size
      ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads);

      try {

           readPropertyFile();

           for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++) {
                service.submit(new ReadTask(durationOfRun, sleepTime));
           }
      }
 }

 private static void readPropertyFile() throws IOException {
      prop.load(Read.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties"));

      threads = Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty("NUMBER_OF_THREADS"));
      durationOfRun = Long.parseLong(prop.getProperty("TOTAL_RUNNING_TIME"));
      sleepTime = Long.parseLong(prop.getProperty("SLEEP_TIME"));
 }
```

Below is my ReadTask class.

```
class ReadTask implements Runnable {
     private long durationOfRun;
     private long sleepTime;

     public ReadTask(long durationOfRun, long sleepTime) {
          this.durationOfRun = durationOfRun;
          this.sleepTime = sleepTime;
     }

     @Override
     public void run() {

          long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
          long endTime = startTime + (durationOfRun*60*1000);

          //Each thread is running less than endTime
          while(System.currentTimeMillis() <= endTime) {

               //Do whatever you want to do

          }

     Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
     }
}
```

If you take a look into my run method, I have a while loop which will check the time. So this approach of making each thread run for particular duration of time is correct or not? Or is there any better way also? Please ignore my ignorance if there are any other better approach or this will also serve the purpose?

Let me know if there are any thread safety issues here as well?

**What I am looking for is each thread should run for 30 minutes and if the time for that thread has finished, then complete the task on which it is running currently and do not take anything else after that, just like we have `shutdown` for `ExecutorService`.** If there is any better approach or better design than this. Please provide me some example so that I can learn that stuff just from my knowledge point of view. Thanks for the help.

**UPDATE:-**

If you take a look into my while loop in the run method, inside that while loop I will be trying to make a `Select call to the database`. So what I am looking is something like this- As soon as the time for that thread is finished, it will not make any other select call to the database and finished whatever it was doing previously. Just like `shutdown` works for `ExecutorService`.

And I don't want this scenario- as soon as the time for that thread is finished, it will timeout the thread as it might be possible, that particular thread was doing select to database in that period?

Comment: The issue I see is if you have some kind of long running or block process, this could potentially mean the thread will run for at *least* required run time, but may run longer. You could use a master thread whose sole purpose is to interrupt threads after a given period of time, but this assumes that the child threads support interruptions

Comment: Thanks MadProgrammer for the suggestion. Can you provide me some example from which I can understand more and which will fulfill my problem scenario. I am not sure how master thread will interrupt the child thread.

Comment: By the way, MadProgrammer, can you please explain me in more clear way what is the potential problem with the above design? Sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: Thread.sleep(sleepTime); seems to have no useful purpose.

Comment: while(System.currentTimeMillis() <= endTime) should have an application-shutdown out.

Comment: @ChuckFricano, what do you mean by shutdown out? Sorry for my ignorance as I am learning stuffs.

Comment: @FarhanJamal - Example:  while (keepAlive && System.currentTimeMillis() < dropDeadTime) -  At application termination, keepAlive should be changed from true to false to cause the loop to end.

Comment: hmmm :(. I got confused now more. Can you provide me an example basis on my problem scenario, then I will be able to understand better what you are trying to say?

Comment: If you have a loop that stays alive doing something for 30 minutes and the loop starts at 10:00am and the user wants to stop the aplication at 10:05am. What happens? The loop wants to run for 25 more minutes.

Comment: In my case what will happen is, each thread will work for 30 minutes and if the time is finished  then execute whatever it was doing previously and after that don't make any select call to the database for that thread. See my updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the concerns I have with this design, is what if the amount of work being done within the while-loop takes more to them the time our?

For example

```
while(System.currentTimeMillis() <= endTime) {

    calaculateTheMeaningOfLife();

}
```

What happens now? What's stopping the thread, or encouraging it to check the timeout? The samething will occur if you have a blocking operation, such as a File or socket read/write

You could try to interrupt the thread, but there is no guareentee that this will help

Comment: Thanks MadProgrammer for the suggestions. How I understand this while loop is. Correct me If I am wrong. If you take a look into the while loop in the run method, inside that while loop I will be trying to make a Select call to the database. So I think this will happen, as soon as the time for that thread is finished, it will not make any other select call to the database and finished whatever it was doing previously. Am I right? If this is the case, then that's what I am looking for.

Comment: Yes, so long as, for what ever reason, nothing blocks the thread. While the select call is been made, the thread will be unable to process the timeout. The while loop, under best conditions, will only guarantee that the thread will live for at least the timeout (which I think said was 30 minutes)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the time limit to the the executor. You need to cast the executor returned by Executors and set the time limit:

```
ThreadPoolExecutor service = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
service.setKeepAliveTime(1800, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Taken from "Java Concurrency in Practice" by Brian Goetz.

Comment: This does not set a time limit for a thread to run.  See the JavaDoc for setKeepAliveTime().

Comment: Yes, you're right. My mistake. And now, thinking about it, it wouldn't make sense to force the shutdown of a thread abruptly. Thanks Chuck.